# Running a meek server (bridge) in Debian

Tags: meek

I'm trying to add meek pluggable support to an existing (working) obfs3/4 bridge in Debian 9. Due to the [important note](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/meek#Howtorunameek-serverbridge) in tor trac the second instance is create using '/usr/sbin/tor-instance-create second'. I need to link second tor instance to meek.
However need some help to understand how build the meek git package as a complete newbie to 'go lang'. 
So far below tasks are completed.

> cd ~
>   git clone https://github.com/arlolra/meek curl -O
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.7.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
>   tar xvf go1.7.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
>   sudo chown -R root:root./go
>   sudo mv go /usr/local
>   cd meek/meek-server
>   go build
>    meek-server executable is created.

1. Should I copy the contents of ~/meek/meek-server/torrc to second instance torrc (/etc/tor/instances/second/torrc ) and then run 'systemctl start tor@second'?
2. How to create the [cert.pem and key.pem](https://gitweb.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/meek.git/tree/meek-server/torrc) described in the line 6?

Appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not neccesary to copy all the content, that is just and example. The key lines for a simple configuration are:

> ```
> ServerTransportPlugin meek exec [meek-serverLocation] --port [meek-serverPortNumber] --disable-tls  --log [FileToWriteMeekLog]
>  ExtORPort auto
> ```

(Adding this to the *torrc* file of your tor instance will use meek with *http*, so you don't need the keys)

2. If you want to run meek with https, meek have to stablish a TLS connection. Than mean that you need a certificate and a private key.

With OpenSSL you can generate a private key and a self-signed certificate.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out cert.pem
```

Then the lines to add in the *torrc* file of your tor instance would be:

```
ServerTransportPlugin meek exec [meek-serverLocation] --port [meek-serverPortNumber] --cert [yourCertLocation] --key [yourKeyLocation] --log [FileToWriteMeekLog]
ExtORPort auto
```

Format Note: In the first configuration lines, code format is not shown if not adding also blockquote format. If someone knows how to fix this, edit please(and also delete this line if properly fixed)